como hacer un grafico con minor ticks usando pandas y numpy
Cómo puedo añadir ticks menores a un plot que se hace usando numpy? Tengo un archivo con dos columnas A y B, necesito multiplicar cada una por un factor diferente usando numpy, y quiero graficarlas (hay varios archivos y quiero graficarlos todos en subtrazados) con ticks menores, pero numpy no tiene atributo para ticks menores.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
fig, plt= plt.subplots(7,1, sharex=True,figsize=(5,12))
file = pd.read_csv('file1.txt',header=0,delimiter= '\s+', index_col=False)
plt[0].plot(file.A.multiply(33.4),file.B.multiply(1/144))

Intente usar
plt.xticks.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))

no funciona con numpy

Primero de todo, el identificador plt inicialmente hace referencia al módulo matplotlib.pyplot ya que importas así:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a partir de:
fig, plt = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(5, 12))

a plt se le reasigna otro valor, el segundo componente de la tupla de salida de matplotlib.pyplot.subplots, un array con referencias a las distintas instancias de Axes. Ahora ya no podrás llamar a nuevas clases, funciones, etc del módulo importado.
Esto hace que tu intento genere algo como:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'xticks'

Cambia el nombre de esa variable, convencionalmente se hace:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(5, 12))
file = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', header=0, delimiter=r'\s+', index_col=False)
axs[0].plot(file.A.multiply(33.4), file.B.multiply(1 / 144))

Dicho esto, para especificar nuevas marcas menores, debes aplicarlo sobre cada subplot:
axs[0].xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
axs[1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
# ...

o también puedes aplicarlos a todos de una vez  con:
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))


Edición
Agrego un ejemplo completo reproducible:
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

files = [
    StringIO("A B\n4 1\n 5 2\n 9 3\n 12 4\n"),
    StringIO("A B\n4 1\n 6 2\n 8 3\n 12 4\n"),
    StringIO("A B\n4 1\n 7 2\n 10 3\n 12 4\n"),
    StringIO("A B\n4 1\n 8 2\n 9 3\n 12 4\n"),
    StringIO("A B\n4 1\n 5 2\n 8 3\n 12 4\n"),
    StringIO("A B\n4 1\n 8 2\n 10 3\n 12 4\n"),
    StringIO("A B\n4 1\n 7 2\n 9 3\n 12 4\n")
    ]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(files), 1, sharex=True, figsize=(5, 12))
for file, ax in zip(files, axs):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, delimiter=r'\s+', index_col=False)
    ax.plot(df.A.multiply(33.4), df.B.multiply(1 / 144))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
plt.show()

StringIO se usa para emular los archivos en disco, si la lista files contiene las rutas a los archivos deseados en vez de las instancia de StringIO funcionará igual. El resultado del ejemplo es:


Lo he intentado antes y esto provoca otro error:'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

@rexa algo debes estar haciendo que no muestra en el código. He editado la respuesta y agregado al final un ejemplo completo que puedes copiar y pegar tal cual para probarlo. Si no consigues que te funcione en tu caso, edita la pregunta y añade (sin eliminar nada de lo que tienes ahora) el nuevo código, completo para poder reproducirlo y vemos a ver que pasa.
